# using javascript variable in MVC3 Razor view engine

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible?

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Link text", "Action Name", new { id = *JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE* })
```

Please explain with example code.

Comment: No, it's not possible. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I need pass a parameter which i get from javascript. How can i solve my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No it is not possible, because .NET MVC 3 is server side code and is evaluated before being sent to the client, and javascript is Client side code which runs only once it is ON the client

BUT the reverse is possible:

```
var jsVar = "@yourMvcVar";
```

Answer (score 77):

**It actually is very much possible with the following:**

```
var hello = "Great Job!";

var text = "@Html.ActionLink( "Link text", "Action Name", new { id = "JSVar" })"
text = text.replace("JSVar",hello);
```

As easy as that! :)

All the @Html.Action link does is create a url string so doing replace on it is the same as replace on any javascript string

Comment: Good workaround! Just make sure that the replacement code is robust, maybe adopt a string.Format type approach: `var text = "@Html.ActionLink( "Link text", "Action Name", new { id = "{0}" })";` not sure if the {0} will work in that helper, but you get my drift

Comment: I'd accept this answer instead of the one accepted now.

Comment: n.b. "{0}" is not a good replace target here since the brackets get URLencoded