# How to use javascript variable in html table tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have declared a variable lenght in my javascript tag and now i want to use that 'length'
variable in html table tag how to use that in razor engine.
i have tried

```
<table>
<tr>
@for(var i=0;i<@lenght;i++)//this is not working

  {some code}
  </tr>
  </table>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: length or lenght? The correct spelling is length.

Comment: You will probably find your solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287484/using-javascript-variable-in-mvc3-razor-view-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `length` variable is defined in javascript, it only "lives" in the browser.

Razor code is executed on the server, so you cannot access this variable.

You could try to build the table in the browser using javascript.