# Convert javascript string to C# string in MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning MVC 5 using C# and javascript.
I've spent 2 hours searching solutions for converting javascript string to C# string and vice versa.
But I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. JavaScript code executes within the client browser and C# code executes on the IIS server. There is no shared memory. Are you asking how to pass a string argument between the two?

Comment: Please supply some code to help explain what you are trying to achieve. Taken out of context, it's hard to understand what you are ultimately looking for.

Comment: look at this question maybe is what are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287484/using-javascript-variable-in-mvc3-razor-view-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but if you need to use a string from client-side JavaScript in your server side C#, you can always POST back to an action of your controller with Ajax.

JavaScript:

```
var testString = "Hello, World!"

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Test/TestAction",
        data: testString,
        success: function (data) {
            // write your function which will call on success
        }});
```

And in your controller...

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test(string id)
    {
        // id is "Hello, World!"
        // do whatever you want with that string here
    }

}
```