# Access javascript variable from razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my Model, there is a dictionary named Feeds. I need to access a particular item in Feeds from javascript code:

```
 var feedID = $sourceRow.attr('id');
 var jobDescriptionMaximumLength = @Model.Feeds[Convert.ToInt32(<text>feedID</text>)];
```

This doesn't work. Could you please what I am doing wrong and what would be the right approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13652417/1731706

Comment: @daniel Are you saying this is impossible?

Comment: Can you say more than "This doesn't work"?  Can you add a debugger and step through it and see what happens?

Comment: check the link again :)

Comment: @nurdyguy The error is "The name 'text' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @daniel Can you clarify how that approach can be applied? I tried this without success:                          var jobDescriptionMaximumLength = @Model.Feeds[Convert.ToInt32("feedIDVar")];
                        jobDescriptionMaximumLength = jobDescriptionMaximumLength.replace("feedIDVar", feedID);

Comment: The smoking gun in his case is the actionlink: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

Comment: I figured it was something along those lines.  It just means it is trying to read 'feedID' as javascript instead of as part of the razor.  Try one of the syntaxes here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to assign the dictionary (your `Feeds` Property value) to a javascript variable and then you can access it in your client side script.

If your `Feeds` property is of type `Dictionary<int,string>`, you will get something like this in your feeds property.

```
{1: "StringVal1", 2: "StringVal2"}
```

From this javascript object, you can access your dictionary item value using the key.

Code for your razor view will be

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model YourNameSpaceHere.YourViewModelTypeHere

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

     var feeds = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Feeds));

     console.log(feeds);

     var feedId = 2; // replace with real value to check
     alert(feeds[feedId]);
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively , you may consider making an Ajax call with the feed id to an end point which returns the complex object you want.

Comment: No, the dictionary is not just <int, string>, but <int, SomeComplexObject>.

Comment: You should be able to access it from your JavaScript object.