# combine razor and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can i combine razor and java script

I want to do this :

```
                @{Session["type"] = $(this).attr("id");}
```

I do that, but i got an error.

I've tried this but it's not work for me.

[using javascript variable in MVC3 Razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287484/using-javascript-variable-in-mvc3-razor-view-engine)

And here is my code:

```
                $(document).on("click", ".btn-group", function() {
                var t = $(this).attr("id");

                var text = "@{Session["type"] = "JSVar";}";
                text = text.replace("JSVar", t);
            });
```

Can any one give me suggestion?

Comment: `Session` is server side. Javascript is client side. If you want to set the value of session property, then you need to send the data to the server.

Comment: i know that , with query string ,but i can do that because my action cant get new parameters (some reason)

Comment: there is any way to send data to server without post data (form or action link)

Comment: you cant set server side variables from client side

Comment: @user3726322 any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In this case, you need to do it in the controller. Also, isn't a good practice to *change* Session values in the view. Try something like this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeType(int type) {
    Session["type"] = type;
}
```

In your javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-group", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ChangeType")",
        data: { type: $(this).attr("id") },
    });
});
```