# Javascript Passing a Parameter to a Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to call the propDetails function and pass an ID to it. Then pass the same ID to the Static controller but I keep on getting an error: "id = id" (second ID doesn't exist).

I am sorry for this silly question and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

```
function propDetails(id) {
    var $detailDiv = $('#detailsDiv'), url = $(this).data('url');

     $.get( '@Url.Action("PropDetails", "Static", new { id = id })', function(data) {
            $('#detailsDiv').html(data);
        });
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: `id` isn't available when your Razor code renders.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287484/using-javascript-variable-in-mvc3-razor-view-engine

Comment: In the long run you would want to render a form to serialize your id as part of the request, written as $("form).serialize(). My original answer was not answering the question.

Comment: @Amy Thank you Amy, the link above helped me a lot! Really cool JS trick!

Answer (score 0):

The `id` variable is not available in the Razor helper, what you can do is concatenate the `id` after the `Url.Action` helper has finished:

```
function propDetails(id) {
    var $detailDiv = $('#detailsDiv'), url = $(this).data('url');   
    $.get('@Url.Action("PropDetails", "Static")' + id, function(data) {
            $('#detailsDiv').html(data);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the long run you would want to render a form to serialize your id as part of the request, written as `$("form").serialize()`. 
It is much easier to append more fields to an action that uses a complex type as a parameter. Your new code would look as follows:

```
$.get($detailDiv.find("form").attr("action"),$detailDiv.find("form").serialize(), function(data){
     $('detailsDiv').html(data);
});
```

Your form object would be created in your HTTPGET request in MVC, returning the view with your built `@Html.BeginForm()` helper, which is part of innerHtml of *detailsDiv*,  that can then be serialized using `$("form").serialize()`

I hope this is clear and fully answers how to fix the issue. I will modify if it is off base and adds more muddle to the mix of Javascript and MVC.